# Review of "Menu program"

Tags: java

Can anyone review my program and state where I could improve it, even in terms of comments, validation, etc?

```
package assessed_practical_2;

//Importing Resources (Random)
import java.util.Random;

//Importing Resources (Scanner)
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {

    /**
     * Scanner used for input within program
     */
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Main method that provides user with a menu in which each number
     * represents a different method (e.g addtion) that they can carry out
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Declare variable for user's option and defaulting to 0
            int menuOption = 0;
            do {
                // Setting menuOption equal to return value from showMenu();
                menuOption = showMenu();

                // Switching on the value given from user
                switch (menuOption) {

                case 1:
                    add();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    subtract();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    guessRandomNumber();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printLoop();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Quitting Program...");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");

                }// End of switch statement

            } while (menuOption != 5);

            // Exiting message when user decides to quit Program
            System.out.println("Thanks for using this Program...");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Error Message
            System.out.println("Sorry problem occured within Program");
            // flushing scanner
            scanner.next();
        } finally {
            // Ensuring that scanner will always be closed and cleaning up
            // resources
            scanner.close();
        }

    }// End of main Method

    /**
     * Method that prints menu to screen and gets returns user's option from menu
     * @return Returns user Option
     */
    public static int showMenu() {

        // Declaring var for user option and defaulting to 0
        int option = 0;

        // Printing menu to screen
        System.out.println("Menu:");
        System.out.println("1.Add");
        System.out.println("2.Subtract");
        System.out.println("3.Guess a Random Number");
        System.out.println("4. Print many times");
        System.out.println("5. Quit Program");

        // Getting user option from above menu
        System.out.println("Enter Option from above...");
        option = scanner.nextInt();

        return option;

    }// End of showMenu

    /**
     * Method that adds two random numbers (from 1-100) and take a user guess
     * for the addition.Then outputs certain statements dependent if user guess
     * is correct or not.
     */
    public static void add() {

        // Setting up new random
        Random random = new Random();

        // Declaring Integers
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int result;
        int input;
        //defaulting input to 0
        input = 0;
        // Declaring boolean for valid user answer (Defaulted to false)
        boolean validAnswer = false;
        //Declaring boolean for correct user answer (default to false)
        boolean correctAnswer=false;
        do {
            // Create two random numbers between 1 and 100
            num1 = random.nextInt(100);
            num1++;
            num2 = random.nextInt(100);
            num2++;

            //Do while loop that loops until user gives valid input
            do {
                //validAnswer set to true to avoid infinite loop
                validAnswer = true;
                // Displaying numbers for user and getting user input for answer
                System.out.println("Adding numbers...");
                System.out.printf("What is: %d + %d? Please enter answer below", num1,num2);
                result = num1 + num2;
                try {
                    input = scanner.nextInt();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Print error message
                    System.out.println("Sorry, Invalid entry for Addition...Please Retry!");
                    // flush scanner
                    scanner.next();
                    validAnswer = false;
                }
            } while (!validAnswer);

            // Line break for code clarity
            System.out.println();

            // if else statement to determine if answer is correct
            if (result == input) {

                System.out.println("Well done, you guessed corectly!");
                correctAnswer = true;
            } else {

                System.out
                        .println("Sorry incorrect, Please guess another Addition");
                correctAnswer = false;
            }
        } while (!correctAnswer);

    }// End of add

    /**
     * Method that subtracts two random numbers (from 1-100) and takes a user
     * guess for the subtraction. Then outputs certain statements dependent if
     * user guess is correct or not.
     */
    public static void subtract() {

        // Setting up random
        Random random = new Random();

        // Declaring Integers
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int result;
        int input;
        //set input to 0
        input = 0;
        // Declaring boolean for validity of userAnswer (Defaulted to false)
        boolean validAnswer = false;
        //Declaring boolean for correct user answer (default to false)
        boolean correctAnswer=false;
        do {
            // Create two random numbers between 1 and 100
            num1 = random.nextInt(100);
            num1++;
            num2 = random.nextInt(100);
            num2++;

            do {
                // Set correctAnwer to true to avoid infinite iterations
                validAnswer = true;
                // Displaying numbers for user and getting user input for answer
                System.out.println("Subtracting numbers...");
                System.out.printf("What is: %d - %d? Please enter answer below", num1,num2);
                result = num1 - num2;

                try {
                    input = scanner.nextInt();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Print error message
                    System.out.println("Sorry, Invalid entry entry for subtraction...Please retry!");
                    // flush scanner
                    scanner.next();
                    validAnswer = false;
                }
            } while (!validAnswer);

            // Line break for code clarity
            System.out.println();

            // if else statement to determine if answer is correct
            if (result == input) {

                System.out.println("Well done, you guessed corectly!");
                correctAnswer = true;
            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry incorrect, Please attempt another subtraction");
                correctAnswer = false;
            }
        } while (!correctAnswer);

    }// end of subtract

    /**
     * A method that generates a random number between 1 and 10
     * @return randomNumber (Returns random number between 1 and 10 inclusive)
     */
    public static int generateRandomNumber() {

        //setting up random
        Random random = new Random();
        // Declaring int for random number and defaulting to 0
        int randomNumber = 0;
        // Assigning randomNumber between 1 and 10
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
        randomNumber++;
        //Trace code, Remember to take out!
        System.out.println("Trace: Random no is:" + randomNumber);
        return randomNumber;

    }// end of generateRandomNumber

    /**
     * Method that allows user to guess a random number between a set range. A
     * message will then be displayed on screen to let them know if they were
     * correct or not.
     */
    public static void guessRandomNumber() {

        // declare var for user guess and default to zero
        int userGuess = 0;
        // declare boolean relating to if number is valid
        boolean validNumber = false;
        // declare boolean relating to if guess is correct
        boolean correctGuess = false;
        // declaring int equal to return value from generateRandomNumber();
        int secretNumber = generateRandomNumber();

        //Do while loop that runs until user guesses correctly
        do {

            //Do while loop that runs until a valid entry is given (i.e. int)
            do {
                try {
                    //do while loop ensuring that user guess is between 1 and 10
                    do {
                        // Get user guess (between 1 and 10)
                        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10...");
                        userGuess = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 10) {
                            validNumber = false;
                            System.out.println("Please Ensure number is between 1 and 10");
                        }else {
                            validNumber=true;
                        }
                    } while (!validNumber);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //Print error message
                    System.out.println("Sorry invalid entry...");
                    // Flush scanner
                    scanner.next();
                    validNumber = false;
                }
            } while (!validNumber);

            //If else statement that outputs a message informing user if guess correct
            if (userGuess == secretNumber) {

                System.out.println("Guess correct, well done!");
                correctGuess = true;

            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry guess Incorrect please try again!");
                correctGuess = false;
            }
        } while (!correctGuess);
    }// end ofGuessRandomNumber


    /**
     * Method that allows user to enter a string they want and print it a
     * certain no of times
     */
    public static void printLoop() {
        // Declaring and initialising Variables
        int noOfTimes = 0;
        String print = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter what you would like to print");
            print = scanner.next();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //error message
            System.out.println("Please give a Valid Entry...");
            // flush scanner
            scanner.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter how many times you wish to print...");
        noOfTimes = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < noOfTimes; counter++) {

            System.out.println(print);
        }
    }// End of printLoop

}// End of Class
```

Comment: Have you handed in this homework yet?

Comment: No no yet lol, Why do you ask?

Comment: I'm grateful that you accepted my answer. But, I would suggest that you hold off on accepting so soon -- when people see that an answer is accepted it reduces their incentive to answer themselves. So, in future, think about waiting a bit to see if more answers (hopefully better ones) come in. Still, thank you.

Comment: I know Profs an TAs might require you comment *EVERYTHING*, but never put inane comments in your code in real life. Everyone knows `import x` imports x, and `switch(x)` switches on x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thoughts:

You have this whole thing as all static. That's fine for a small simple program like this, but it might be better practice for you to make most of the methods into instance methods, and then in `main()`, instantiate it and call a driver method on that class. Static things can get messy in java when the logic gets more complicated. So, I would pull out most of the stuff that you have in your main method and put it into an instance method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assignment2 assignment = new Assignment2();
    assignment.start();
}
```

Also, unless you're required to have your class named Assignment2, I would suggest changing it to something more descriptive (it should tell you what it *does* not what it *is*).

Might want to rename a few methods also. For example, `showMenu()` doesn't just show a menu, it also gets input from the user, so maybe rename that to something like `getSelection()` (or something).

Let's talk about your `add()` method.

```
  do {
        num1 = random.nextInt(100);
        num1++;
        num2 = random.nextInt(100);
        num2++;

        do {
            validAnswer = true;

            System.out.println("Adding numbers...");
            System.out.printf("What is: %d + %d? Please enter answer below", num1,num2);
            result = num1 + num2;
            try {
                input = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, Invalid entry for Addition...Please Retry!");
                scanner.next();
                validAnswer = false;
            }
        } while (!validAnswer);
```

Instead of assigning num1 and num2 on one line, and on the next, incrementing them, put that on one line.

```
num1 = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
num2 = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

Also, some minor issues with spacing. Change `boolean correctAnswer=false;` to `boolean correctAnswer = false;`

Also, it's bad practice to catch `Exception`. Catch and handle only the ones you expect to deal with -- If Java makes you surround something with a try catch, *only catch the ones you need to catch and are prepared to handle*. The way you're doing it, if something throws a null pointer exception, your program won't give you useful crash reporting. I *think* what you really want to catch is `InputMismatchException`. So, catch that or leave an explanation as to why you're swallowing all exceptions in a comment.

Your `add()` and `subtract()` methods are pretty much exactly the same. You should think about making them into one method that accepts an argument for which behaviour to exhibit.

You spend a lot of lines getting and validating input from the user. Think about writing a helper function to do that all in one place:

```
private int getInt(String message, int low, int high) {
    int num;
    boolean invalid = true;

    do {
        System.out.printf("Please enter an integer between %d and %d: ");

        try {
            num = scanner.nextInt();

            if (num >= low && num <= high) {
                invalid = false;
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException x) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again");
        }
    } while (invalid);
}
```

Something like that (if you need to use a do-while. Personally, I try to avoid them but it looks like you like them, and maybe it's part of your assignment).

Those are just a few things that I would suggest you think about. The main problems I see mostly relate to code duplication, so really think about ways to reduce that.

Comment: Note, also, that the way my `getInt()` is written isn't ideal -- in particular, there's no point in having the `invalid` flag since basically it just infinite loops until something valid is entered. That's just meant as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Minor comments here since scott_fakename has provided a pretty good start...

Extract the user input part from `show_menu` into its own method, so that each method is only dealing with one thing.

You have some idea of showing 'tracing' messages for debugging/troubleshooting, ever considered using a logging framework? Not sure if this is beyond what you need to hand in this assignment, just a thought...

I also think using one static class-wide `Random` instance is good enough for all the random number generation.

As for consolidating `add` and `subtract` methods into a single one that takes an extra parameter to control the calculation, you can consider using enumerations to indicate the different modes. E.g.:

```
enum Mode {
    ADD, SUBTRACT;
}

...

public void calculation(Mode mode) {
    ...
    int num1, num2, result;
    ...
    switch (mode) {
    case ADD:
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case SUBTRACT:
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

In fact you'll probably want to keep this as a simple method itself (similar to your `generateRandomNumber`, and have an outside method to get the user input (following scott_fakename's suggestion) to do the comparison.